# Key value for this row was changed or deleted at the data store. The local row is now deleted

Tags: delphi, ado

Migrating 1.5 million lines of D7,BDE,Paradox to XE2,ADO,MS-SQL.

We have a TDBLookupComboBox that works fine. We provide the user with an ellipsis button so they can add or delete records from the combo box's ListSource table while the combo box is visible.

If the user clicks on the ellipsis, we let them edit the table and then we Refresh the comboboxes datasource, like this:

```
EditTable.ShowModal; // user edits ListSource.Dataset table
Form1.DBComboBox1.ListSource.DataSet.Refresh
```

This worked fine in the Paradox world.

In the SQL/ADO world, if the user deletes a record from the ListSource, we get the message on the Refresh statement above:

```
Key value for this row was changed or deleted at the data store. 
The local row is now deleted.
```

This occurs even if the record the user deleted was not the currently selected item in the combo box.

We don't understand *why* this is happening now but not in the Paradox version.

Our solution has been (after the user edits) to close and open the ListSource dataset as shown below, but this is clumsy (and we'll have to replicate in almost 100 places we do this kind of thing.)

Here's our current fix:

```
var
  KeyBeforeUserEdit: Integer;

KeyBeforeUserEdit:= Form1.DBComboBox.KeyValue;
EditTable.ShowModal; // user edits ListSource.Dataset table
Form1.DBComboBox1.ListSource.DataSet.Close;
Form1.DBComboBox1.ListSource.DataSet.Open;
if Form1.DBComboBox1.ListSource.DataSet.Locate('UniqueKey', KeyBeforeUserEdit, []) then 
  From1.DBComboBox1.KeyValue := KeyBeforeUserEdit;
```

Any alternate suggestions or explanations why this is necessary?

Comment: It is hard to say what is wrong, probably you would have to build a sample application which describes the problem. The other solution would be to operate on detached dataset (IMHO great feature of ADO) and updating it manually.

Answer (score 0):

I can't know for sure what is going on but you may be able to simplify your migration (albeit not good practice) in the following way.

ShowModal is a virtual function so you can override it in the class EditTable belongs to (TEditTable?) providing that you have that source. Within the unit add the Form1 unit to the uses clause ***in the implementation section*** (if it is not already there) and add your override as follows

```
function TEditTable.ShowModal : integer;
var
  KeyBeforeUserEdit: Integer;
begin
  KeyBeforeUserEdit:= Form1.DBComboBox.KeyValue;
  Result := inherited ShowModal; // user edits ListSource.Dataset table
  Form1.DBComboBox1.ListSource.DataSet.Close;
  Form1.DBComboBox1.ListSource.DataSet.Open;
  if Form1.DBComboBox1.ListSource.DataSet.Locate('UniqueKey', KeyBeforeUserEdit, []) then 
    From1.DBComboBox1.KeyValue := KeyBeforeUserEdit; 
end;
```

It is a bit of a kludge but may be pragmatic and save a lot of work.